# Python Django: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable MatchAll object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am facing below error when try to query using 'Q' in a viewset. It will work without any issues if I use this in a management command file.

My view.

```
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
class ClipartViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ClipartSerializer
    queryset = Clipart.objects.filter(is_active=True).all()

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Some extra logic
        # qs = Clipart.objects.filter(name="Apes") #This line will work without any issues
        qs = Clipart.objects.filter(Q(name="Apes") | Q(name="Dog"))  # This line will show error

        print(qs)

        return super(ClipartViewSet, self).list(self, request, **kwargs)
```

### Error:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/s/configurator/cliparts
backend_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
backend_1        |     response = get_response(request)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
backend_1        |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
backend_1        |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
backend_1        |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
backend_1        |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
backend_1        |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
backend_1        |     raise exc
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
backend_1        |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
backend_1        |   File "/backend/mycomp/apps/ecommerce/configurator/views/design_views.py", line 109, in list
backend_1        |     qs = Clipart.objects.filter(Q(name="Apes") | Q(name="Dog"))  # This line will show error
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
backend_1        |     return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/safedelete/queryset.py", line 72, in filter
backend_1        |     return super(SafeDeleteQueryset, queryset).filter(*args, **kwargs)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 941, in filter
backend_1        |     return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
backend_1        |     clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
backend_1        |     self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1391, in add_q
backend_1        |     clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1413, in _add_q
backend_1        |     split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
backend_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1281, in build_filter
backend_1        |     arg, value = filter_expr
backend_1        | TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable MatchAll object
```

Comment: What is a `SafeDeleteQueryset`, and does it fail if you stop using that?

Comment: How do you import `Q`?

Comment: Could you print the `print(Q(name="Apes"))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely you implement the wrong `Q`, you import this with:

```
from django.db.models import Q


@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
class ClipartViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ClipartSerializer
    queryset = Clipart.objects.filter(is_active=True).all()

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        qs = Clipart.objects.filter(Q(name='Apes') | Q(name='Dog'))
        return super(ClipartViewSet, self).list(self, request, **kwargs)
```

that being said, you can simplify the query with an [**`__in`** lookup <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
class ClipartViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ClipartSerializer
    queryset = Clipart.objects.filter(is_active=True).all()

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Some extra logic
        qs = Clipart.objects.filter(name__in=('Apes', 'Dog'))
        print(qs)
        return super(ClipartViewSet, self).list(self, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you. I import wrong Q. I had imported two Qs. One from models and other one from elastic search. That was the reason.

Comment: Thank you! Same here. Elasticsearch Q was used

Comment: Somehow, I made the same mistake today, and I came across this. :)